# Declare new object instance in variable inside a class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, instance

Well, I will be clear, Im getting an error while declaring a variable as an instance of another class.
Both class are in different files and I make a simple example of it to show quickly whats the error.

The error Im getting is the following one:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  New expressions are not supported in this context in Nameclassfile.php on line 6"
```

Im not an expert with php, currently Im running php 8.1 and Im not even sure if is allowed to declare variables as instances of other classes.

Well, my code is:

- First Class file: Nameclassfile.php

```
<?php
    require_once "Valueclassfile.php";
    class NameClass {
        private $name;
        private $value = new ValueClass();

        function __construct() {
            $this->name = "Default name";
        }

        function get_name() {
            return $this->name;
        }

    }
?>
```

- Second Class file: Valueclassfile.php

```
<?php
    class ValueClass {
        private $value;

        function __construct() {
            $this->value = "Default Value";
        }

        function get_value() {
            return $this->value;
        }
    }
?>
```

I hope you can bring me a hand, best regards.

Comment: This and the inability to cast to user defined classes is something I wish PHP had, unfortunately we have to make do with it for now. You're better off using dependency injection since `NameClass` clearly relies on `ValueClass` which, as mentioned, can be passed as an argument to the `__construct` magic method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can definitely declare variables as instances of other classes, but you can only declare static (i.e., compile-time) values for your property initializations.

```
class Foo {
    private $value = 123;
}
```

You can't use code that requires execution (i.e., run-time) like this:

```
class Foo {
    private $value = call_some_function();
}
```

Or this:

```
class Foo {
    private $value = new ValueClass();
}
```

The simple workaround is to just do your initialization in the constructor:

```
class NameClass {
    private $value;

    function __construct() {
        $this->value = new ValueClass();
    }
}
```

Note, with 8.1+ you can use the [constructor property promotion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor.promotion) feature, which does allow instances of `new`:

```
class NameClass {
    function __construct(private $value = new ValueClass()) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just tried both ways, however, when I try to call a method which check if the variable it is initialized, it doesn't work. Example of method: ```function get_value() {
            if ($this->$value) {
                return "Initialized";
            }
            return "Not Initialized";
        }```

Comment: You don't need this method because you're initializing in the constructor. If the constructor fails, it won't create an object -- so it's _not possible_ to have an object with an uninitialized value.

Comment: Also note, `$this->$value` is not `$this->value`.

Comment: Howasky. Yep, you were right. Looks like I were having some mistakes in my php syntax. Im new using this syntax and now the code works fine by using ```$this->value``` Thanks for helping, everything is looking good right now, best regards.